# How to do recursive feature elimination with logistic regression?

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-selection

Can someone provide me a detailed example of using caret's `rfe` function with the glm or glmnet model? I tried something like this:

```
rfe_records <- Example_data_frame

rfe_ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs, method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5, verbose = TRUE, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

number_predictors <- dim(rfe_records)[2]-1

x <- dplyr::select(rfe_records, -outcomeVariable)
y <- as.numeric(rfe_records$outcomeVariable)

glmProfile <- rfe(x, y, rfeControl = rfe_ctrl, sizes = c(1:number_predictors), method="glmnet", preProc = c("center", "scale"), metric = "Accuracy")
print(glmProfile)
```

But the results I'm getting are not what I needed. I specified Accuracy as the metric but I got:

```
Recursive feature selection

Outer resampling method: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 

Resampling performance over subset size:

 Variables   RMSE Rsquared  RMSESD RsquaredSD Selected
         1 0.5047  0.10830 0.04056    0.11869        *
         2 0.5058  0.09386 0.04728    0.11332         
         3 0.5117  0.08565 0.04999    0.10211         
         4 0.5139  0.07490 0.05042    0.10048         
         5 0.5166  0.07678 0.05456    0.09966         
         6 0.5202  0.08203 0.06174    0.10822         
         7 0.5187  0.08471 0.06207    0.10893         
         8 0.5168  0.07850 0.05939    0.09697         
         9 0.5175  0.08228 0.05966    0.10068         
        10 0.5176  0.08180 0.05980    0.10042         
        11 0.5179  0.08015 0.05950    0.09905         

The top 1 variables (out of 1):
   varName
```

Comment: May be off topic for this site since it deals almost exclusively with R programming issues.

Comment: Where do you telll glmnet that you are performing logistic regression?

Comment: Questions about how to use software are generally off topic here. This isn't really a *programming* question, though, so it will be off topic on [SO] as well. It seems to be asking for a tutorial; that's off topic everywhere on the SE system, AFAIK.

Comment: @EdM , in this line -> `glmProfile <- rfe(x, y, rfeControl = rfe_ctrl, sizes = c(1:number_predictors), method="glmnet", preProc = c("center", "scale"), metric = "Accuracy")`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-specify-if-I-want-to-run-a-Caret-package-function-for-classification-or-regression) `caret` uses the class of the outcome variable when it determines whether to use regression or classification with a function like `glmnet` that can do either. According to your code, you specified the outcome variable to be numeric with `as.numeric()` so glmnet chose to do regression, not classification as you intended. Specify your outcome variable as a two-level factor to get classification instead.